# algorithm or technique for matching transactions

Tags: categorical-data, matching

I've got two data sets, one is "expected transaction" another is "actual transactions"

It's something similar to the following

EXPECTED (generated on december 4th)

```
uniqueID  |  expectedPayDate  |  payerName  |  paymentAmount
1324      |  20171215         | cutco       |  100.00
5678      |  20171215         | edgecom     |  200.00
9101      |  20171215         | interslice  |  300.00
```

ACTUAL

```
AnotherID |  actualPayDate    |  payerName  |  paymentAmount
abcd      |  20171214         | cutco       |  100.00
efgh      |  20171215         | edgecom     |  200.00
ijkl      |  20171217         | interslice  |  300.00
```

The actual data have a lot more columns (some the exact same between expected and actual while others are based of rules- either a dict or formula, others seemingly unrelated but might have some correlations), and I have a training data set of matched-up rows

Is there any known technique that I can use to match rows in Expected against rows in Actual?

Comment: This looks like something where [Naive Bayes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naive_Bayes_classifier) might be useful. In any case, I disagree with the close voters (and have voted to Leave Open); this is a *bona fide* probabilistic matching problem.